# Bind directive to controller property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ecmascript-6

New to Angular here:

I would like to conditionally hide my NavBar directive, so I added an attribute as follows:

```
 export function NavbarDirective() {

     'ngInject';

     let directive = {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar/navbar.html',
         scope: {
             hidden: "="
         },
         controller: NavbarController,
         controllerAs: 'navBarVm',
         bindToController: true
     };

     return directive;
 }

 class NavbarController {

     constructor() {
         'ngInject';
     }
 }
```

And use it as follows:

`<lb-navbar hidden="main.loading"></lb-navbar>`

However when `main.loading` becomes false, the NavBar doesn't reappear. How can I fix this?

For now, I've just wrapped in a div as follows:

`<div ng-hide="vm.loading">
    <lb-navbar hidden="main.loading"></lb-navbar>
  </div>`

. . however, I'm looking for the correct way to create a 'pass by reference' binding in a directive.

Comment: may I know, how you used `hidden` variable over html of directive template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a real **angular** issue.

> Since you've use `hidden` to hide element, need to **remove `hidden` attr** of your directive, rather than set `hidden="false"` when you want to reappear it.

```html
<div hidden="true">1.div with hidden="true" (you cant see me)</div>

<br />

<div hidden="false">2.div with hidden="false" (you cant see me)</div>

<br />

<div>3.div without hidden attr (you can only see me)</div>
```

For your case, two solutions,

**1.Just use `ng-hide` replace `hidden`:**

```
<lb-navbar ng-hide="main.loading"></lb-navbar>
```

**2.Another name rather than `hidden` to control visibility:**

Your directive:

```
let directive = {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar/navbar.html',
     scope: {
         myhidden: "="
     },
     controller: NavbarController,
     controllerAs: 'navBarVm',
     bindToController: true,
     link:function(scope,element,attrs){
         scope.$watch('myhidden',function(nv,ov){
             nv ? element.hide() : element.show();
             return false;
         });
     }
 };
```

And markup:

```
<lb-navbar myhidden="main.loading"></lb-navbar>
```

Comment: Ah, of course, everything I needed was already supported. But thank you for showing me why what I was trying to do also didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I'll start to namespace my attributes too, eg 'lb-hide'

Comment: Great, awesome to keep the namespace.